# Java Save Images

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-8

I have written a program that generates images for me.
That works so far, save on the save.

In the method I want to save I have a `WritabelImage`
I make a `BuffertImage` with the `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage ()`. In the debugger of Intellij I can also look at it and it is actually there.

Then I have the output path created as URI and pass this to a `Fil` object.

With `ImageIO.write ()` I would like to combine and save both.
And that does not work.
The path exits.
I tried it with the direct URI and also with the `uri.getPath ()`

I just do not know how to continue.
Can you please help me with that?

```
try {
        String path;
        URI    uri;
        uri = this.getClass().getResource("").toURI();
        path = uri.toString().replace("foo/bar/foobar/generate/", "generate/out/" + name + ".png");
        uri = URI.create(path);
        File          outputFile = new File(uri.getPath());
        BufferedImage bImage     = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
        System.out.println("Saved");
        ImageIO.write(bImage, ".png", outputFile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format name parameter is not supposed to include a dot. Try simply `"png"`